# iptables allow certain ports and disable the rest

Tags: iptables

I have the following scenario:
I only want to allow access to 22, 80 and 443 ports and everything else permit.

My `iptables -L` looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

But I can't get the desired effect, and even from my server I can't ping anything anymore ( can't get on the internet anymore ).

Also, I looked at option to set `INPUT` policy to `DROP` and manually open the desired ports but that didn't take the desired effect either.

Is there any difference in putting the `DROP` policy on `INPUT` chain and manually open the desired ports and the way I did it by dropping all traffic as the last rule.

Thanks a bunch,
Best regards.

Comment: That ruleset looks perfectly fine.  What exactly isn't working?  How are you testing?

Comment: As it can be seen from the ruleset, I can ssh into my server ( it's on my local network ), but from it I can't access anything. I can't even ping 8.8.8.8 ( there's no internet access ) nor I can event access services from my other workstations on that server.

Comment: Maybe add a `LOG` rule just before your `DROP` rule to see what you're dropping? You're not blocking any outbound traffic, and the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule should permit any return traffic from outbound connections.  Might not be an iptables problem.

Comment: Remember that you need to use `-v` to see the complete rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current setup for `INPUT` chain allows clients to connect to your server on tcp 22, 80 and 443 and the **tcp** connections you initiate to be replied. That's it! No *icmp* (for ping), no *udp* (DNS lookups).

Having your `ESTABLISHED, RELATED` rule `ALLOW` all protocols, instead of just *tcp*, should fix the above.

Regarding dropping everything using a rule versus `DROP` policy:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Is the same thing as having:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

As your last rule.

Also, unless you know exactly what you're doing, you should fully allow *loopback* traffic.

Comment: Thanks petry, that's it. I have added icmp rule and a few loopback entries and everything works now. Also, thanks for the clarification on the differences between the DROP policy and dropping the traffic manually.